# iframe not updating when called by javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, iframe

I have a simple vb.net 4.6 web app for a library page.

I have an iFrame that is not refreshing until I close page and open back up.

Everything is on one domain, myLibraryBookCatalog.org.

I have this page, which is a listing of book titles, that contains the iframe and a button- libraryStoreFront.aspx:

```
<div id="myBookListings">
    <iframe id="bookListing" width="600" height="600" src="bookListing.aspx?libraryID=<%=libraryID%>"></iframe>
</div>

<div id="addNewBook">
    <asp:Button ID="btnAddNewBook" runat="server" Text="Add" />
</div>
```

The code behind file, libraryStoreFront.aspx.vb, calls a javascript function like this when the btnAddNewBook button is clicked:

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Me.Page.GetType, "AddNewBook", "updateBookListings();", True)
```

The function,updateBookListings(), is in a file called bookscripts.js and here's what that function looks like:

```
function updateBookListings() {
    console.log("DEBUG: button clicked -- add new book");
    document.getElementById("bookListing").contentDocument.location.reload(true);
}
```

The page, bookListing.aspx, is just a page that displays a table of books.

Even with everything on the same Windows Server 2016, same IIS site, and same domain, I still get this error when that javascript function tries to reload the iframe:

> Cross-origin plugin content from  must have a visible size larger than 400 x 300 pixels, or it will be blocked. Invisible content is always blocked.

I don't see the new updated book listing until I close the book listing page, and re-open...then it's there.

So I know the adding a new book part is working.

But it should be there after the javascript iframe update, correct?

I'm not sure how to update iframe successfully and without the cross-origin warning.

Is there a proper way of doing this?

Comment: I thought it was by (re)setting the `src` attribute but I'm not sure.

Comment: @wazz Hi, I'm sorry I'm not sure what you mean